# Token caching with Mutiny

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

I'm new in reactive programming and trying to wrap my head around base concepts.
Basically, I want to implement a logic, that would return auth token if it's still valid or requests the new one otherwise.
My best take is the code like below:

```java
public class AsyncTokenSupplier implements Supplier<Uni<Token>> {
   private Token cachedToken;

   @Override
   public Uni<Token> get() {
        if (isTokenValid(cachedToken)) {
            return Uni.createFrom().item(cachedToken);
        } else {
            return doGetToken().onItem().invoke(token -> {
                cachedToken = token;
            });
        }
    }

   private Uni<Token> doGetToken() {
      //Api call here
   }

   private boolean isTokenValid(Token token) {
      if (token == null) {
         return false;
      }
      //Expiration check here
   }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't look like a thread safe - if a few threads execute "get()" method in parallel, it could end up in a few new tokens requested at the same time.
I'd appreciate any guidance and recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a thread safety problem that's relatively classic. You might consider an `AtomicReference` to hold the `token` field.

That being said `Uni` has a [`memoize()`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/1.7.0/io/smallrye/mutiny/groups/UniMemoize.html) operator that might just do what you want. You should be able to do something like:

```java
return doGetToken().memoize().until(() -> someExpirationLogic());
```